# Square root of a u128

Tags: rust, square-root, int128

How can the square root of a `u128` be calculated? The resulting number can be a `u128` after some rounding.

`f64` has a [`f64::sqrt` function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.sqrt), but I dont think we should be converting `u128` to `f64`.

Comment: [num::integer::Roots](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/integer/trait.Roots.html)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`Roots`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/integer/trait.Roots.html) trait from the [num](https://crates.io/crates/num) crate (or directly from the [num-integer](https://docs.rs/num-integer/latest/num_integer/) crate):

> `pub fn sqrt(&self) -> Self`
>
> Returns the truncated principal square root of an integer – `⌊√x⌋`
>
> This is solving for `r` in `r² = x`, rounding toward zero. The result will
> satisfy `r² ≤ x < (r+1)²`.

```
use num::integer::Roots; // 0.4.0

fn main() {
    let a: u128 = 42;
    let b = a.sqrt();
    
    assert!(b == 6);
}
```

Comment: This handles u64 internally with a loss  of precision